# How to find compressed or encrypted parts in a packed executable?

Tags: static-analysis, executable, encryption, decryption, decompress

I want to analyze an executable that went through a packer to look for the parts that have been compressed or encrypted. Of course, it also means that I want to find the code for the decompression or decryption procedures in the executable. How can I find these ?

Comment: Generically for all executables packed with any packer? Or generically for all executables packed with a specific packer? Or specifically for a single executable packed with a specific packer?

Comment: Generally for all packer and all executable.If packer Specified, this work is easy

Answer (score 4):

A good way to find compressed or encrypted parts in a binary is entropy investigation, as compressed and encrypted parts show a high degree of disorder (a value of 1 means maximum disorder). I can recommend the tool [binwalk](http://binwalk.org) which produces a graphical output of the memory's entropy. The picture shows a binwalk output, as an example of such a static analysis of an embedded device, showing typical entropies of different memory parts.
[image]

The bottom part is an overlay of the corresponding Ida memory map.

Answer (score 3):

For *most* packers out there:

- The start of the decompression or decryption is pretty much the entry point (with a bit of anti-debugging mixed in, perhaps).
- The end of the decompression or decryption can't be found generically with static analysis.